# Creating a directive for a datepicker, watching model triggers two updates

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I am trying to wrap the [Foundation Datepicker](http://foundation-datepicker.peterbeno.com/example/example.html) into an Angular directive. Here is what I have:

```
angular.module('fdatepicker', [])
.directive('fdatepicker', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      element.fdatepicker('destroy').fdatepicker();
      element.on('blur', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          controller.$setViewValue(element.fdatepicker("getDate"));
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And in my view, the datepicker does appear with the following code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="start_at" fdatepicker>
```

In my controller, the following code:

```
$scope.$watch("start_at", function() {
  console.log("start_at changed to " + $scope.start_at);
});
```

is triggered twice when selecting a date with the datepicker:

```
// start_at changed to Sun Feb 09 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) 
// start_at changed to 02/04/2014
```

I would like to get notified just once, with the `date` object, not the formatted value! How can I decouple the model from the presentation (formatted date) ?